# Preposition used in comparing, "on" or "to"?

Tags: prepositions

> “Yeah, I know,” said Angelina, pulling out her wand and flexing her arm. “But she’s pretty good, actually. **Nothing on you**, of course,” she said, throwing him a very dirty look, “but as we can’t have you . . .”

The above bold phrase is definitely describing Harry is a way better Seeker than Ginny. But would it be more appropriate to use "to" in this case?

> Used to introduce the second element in a comparison:
>
> *the club’s nothing to what it once was*
>
> —[oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to?q=to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the communication of belief about interpersonal mental states.

Nothing to you, of course = I believe that you think that you wouldn't care because you know (you believe) you're better than her, of course.

Nothing on you, of course = I know (I believe) that you're better than her.

They are both idiomatic.